# using gpg-agent between different sessions

Tags: gpg-agent

I am trying to set up `gpg-agent`

When I log in to my machine (via SSH) and invoke `gpg`, it asks for password every time (it does not start `gpg-agent` automatically).

When I start `gpg-agent` manually using:

```
eval "$(gpg-agent --daemon)"
```

then next invocation of `gpg` actually launches the agent, and after typing my password once, I can then use gpg without password. Also, I see a socket has been created in `$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent=`

When I log out and log in again (ssh), I see the socket still exists in `$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent=` and `ps` shows that the agent is running, but every invocation of `gpg` asks for password, as if there was no agent.

I have added this to my `.bashrc`:

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

but that does not seem to help

I find the behaviour of `gpg-agent` very confusing. I am familiar with `ssh-agent` and that behaves straightforward and understandable.

How can I use `gpg-agent` same way as I would use `ssh-agent` ?

**For comparison, this is how `ssh-agent` behaves:**

After I boot my machine and login for the first time, I launch `ssh-add` manually and type my pass phrase once.

Then, every time I log in to my machine (X, console, ssh, ...) I can use the agent (I don't need to type my password again). This is done by adding following line to `.bashrc`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(find /tmp/ssh-*/agent.* -uid $(id -u) -type s -print -quit 2>/dev/null)"
```

Comment: This is why I use [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) to manage both agents...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gpg` does not look for the socket (this is different with the new version 2.1) but for the environment variable `GPG_AGENT_INFO`. This is not set on log in. That is the problem. Obviously you have the option `use-standard-socket` in `gpg-agent.conf` so that the socket name is always the same.

You should set the variable in a login script run a simple script afterwards which checks whether `gpg-agent` is running:

```
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=/path/to/your/HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:42:1
gpg-connect-agent /bye &>/dev/null || gpg-agent --daemon &>/dev/null
```

That is the part for using `gpg`. For SSH you also need `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. The easiest way to get both variables set is to add the line

```
write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info
```

to the config file `gpg-agent.conf` and to run this script after the above:

```
. "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

This is explaned in the `gpg-agent` man page.

Comment: I have added the two lines (EXPORT ... , gpg-connect-agent...)into my `.bashrc` and it seems to work. Could you please explain what does the `:42:1` at the end of the socket mean ? And also, I don't understand the `write-env-file` part. Is this necessary, or is this an alternative solution to the two lines above?

Comment: For GnuPG a static solution (the first two lines) is possible. But for the SSH part you need data from the agent. `write-env-file` (as the man page would have told you) makes `gpg-agent` dump the necessary data; thus this is necessary (for SSH). The OpenPGP part consists of `${path}:${pid}:${protocolversion}`. The path is always the same (due to `use-standard-socket`), the PID is ignored (thus it can be any value), and the protocol version is always 1.

Comment: I am still confused why you mix gpg-agent and SSH together. Aren't these two independent applications ?

Comment: @MartinVegter I misread the question. `gpg-agent` can replace `ssh-agent` (see `--enable-ssh-support`) but it seems you don't do that (that would be on the other host anyway). So you don't need the SSH part but only the first two lines.

Comment: I have now tested your solution. It works, but not between sessions: when I log out and back in (via SSH), I have to give the password again. The agent does not "remember" the password between sessions. In contrast, `SSH agent` works as long as there exists the socket `/tmp/ssh-*/agent.*`

Comment: @MartinVegter Is the `gpg-agent` process killed when you log out? Probably. A killed process cannot remember anything. That raises the question whether `ssh-agent` is (for whatever reason) **not** killed on logout. If that is the difference then the question would be: How to prevent `gpg-agent` from being killed (if that sounds like a good idea at all)? Maybe it has to be started with `nohup`.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. One more question: apart from `export GPG_AGENT_INFO`, will I also need to export `GPG_TTY` ? I read somewhere that I will need to add the following into my .bashrc: `GPG_TTY=$(tty)` and `export GPG_TTY`

Comment: @MartinVegter I wasn't aware of that recommendation. I guess this is relevant only if the console version of `pinentry` is used (that is probably your case). A client to `gpg-agent` can tell `gpg-agent` which terminal it is running on so that `pinentry` is started on the correct terminal. So you should put that code in your startup files.

Comment: In Debian 8, gpg-agent seems to create the socket in /tmp. `eval \`gpg-agent --daemon\`` in my .bash_profile works.

Comment: in fedora 25 with gpg 2.1.13 the gpg-agent ssh socket is here /run/user/${UID}/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the solution in the other answer did not work for me.  At my side `gpg-agent --daemon` ignores `GPG_AGENT_INFO` in the environment and always defines it's own new one, so each login created it's own permanently running process.

But following line did it:

`` for a in . .; do . "${HOME}/.gnupg/pg-agent-info.`uname -n`"; gpg-connect-agent /bye && break; gpg-agent --daemon >"${HOME}/.gnupg/pg-agent-info.`uname -n`"; done ``

- This assumes that you have a `$HOME/.gnupg` directory.  If not, create it with `mkdir ~/.gnupg`

Here is how it works:

- It first sources the old output of the running agent setting
- If this still is valid, it uses it
- else it starts a new daemon and remembers the settings in "${HOME}/.gnupg/pg-agent-info.HOSTNAME"
- A second loop in the `for` then re-reads the information
- If two loops do not help, a third one would not either.

Please note that the hostname is built into the filename, because it may be that you share your home between different computers.

Feel free to improve to get rid of possibly ugly error outputs and possibly create the directory if it is missing.