# How do I make GPG use keys accessed over SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, gpg

I have my GPG keys stored on a remote server (accessible via SSH) due to some technical constraints. Is it possible to make GPG use those keys transferred over ssh, without actually copying them locally?

Answer (score 2):

You can start `gpg-agent` remotely and create remote UNIX socket port forwarding to your host and then use the `gpg-agent` locally. In short

1. Connect to the server and start `gpg-agent` (if it is not running yet) and ensure it stays running. It is listening on socket defined in environment variable `$GPG_AGENT_INFO`. Store the path:

   ```
   eval `gpg-agent --daemon` && echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO
   ```
2. Issue remote unix domain socket forwarding (choose secure `local_path`):

   ```
   ssh -NTfR local_path:remote_path_from_above remoteHost
   ```
3. Kill your local agent and start new one with connection to the remote host:

   ```
   export GPG_AGENT_INFO=local_path
   gpg-connect-agent /bye &>/dev/null || gpg-agent --daemon &>/dev/null
   ```

Based on the knowledge gained in the [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170758/using-gpg-agent-between-different-sessions).

Comment: A. For the socket forwarding in step 2, you need the relatively recent OpenSSH 6.7 [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/609321/). For instance, Ubuntu Trusty LTS is still at 6.6.

Comment: B. Your step 3 will start an extra `gpg-agent` running locally. I think what you meant is to run `gpg`, not another `gpg-agent`. So, `export GPG_AGENT_INFO=local_path; gpg --encrypt --recipient ...`.

Comment: In this scheme, it is unclear how the remote `gpg-agent`, the only one that has access to the keys, will be able to ask for passphrases. Perhaps `pinentry-curses` might work (not sure), but anything GUI-related can't possibly work.